# Can I re-use an Azure host name?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an Azure app service hosted as [somehostname].azurewebsites.net.  Can I reuse that same host name if I delete the existing resource first?

If so, is there a delay before the prior usage of that host name is released?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Names are only reserved until the resources are deleted. If you delete your web app, then the name is available again.

There may or may not be a delay, based on how things are managed.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can reuse the host name pretty much immediately.

One caveat to note is that if you create the site in a different region, your new site will end up having a different ip address than the old one. This means that you might not be able to access your site until the DNS propagation completes.

You can test the exact process by creating a test site, deleting it, and then recreating it.