# How to reuse a host name 'something.azurewebsites.net' on a different Azure account

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have two Azure accounts. With the first account I created an App Service (ASP.NET Core Web App on URL: [something].azurewebsites.net). Then I decided to move it to my different account, so I deleted completely - App Service, App Service Plan and also the whole Resource Group.

When I am trying to create a new App Service on the second account (with exactly the same URL [something].azurewebsites.net), I am getting the error: *The host name [something].azurewebsites.net is already assigned to another Azure website.* I am 100% sure that it was deleted from the first account.

```
ExtendedCode": "54003","MessageTemplate": The host name {0} is already assigned to another Azure website.","Parameters": ["[something].azurewebsites.net"],"Code": "Conflict"
```

Comment: maybe someone else took it between your deletion and your attempt to create in the second one.

Comment: Or Microsoft binds it to the old account for x days, or even forever, for security reasons.  Otherwise shady people could put up fake replacement sites for phishing and malware infection.

Comment: I would accept that but at least it should be mentioned somewhere in the doc.

Comment: but answering your question, the proper way is by support ticket, otherwise there's no other way to keep the domain without a risk of someone else take the domain while you're moving to another subscription.

Comment: According to David Makogan (Works at Microsoft), host names are not held after the resource is deleted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39647651/can-i-re-use-an-azure-host-name. I'd give it another try a few hours later and see if you are able to grab it. Please report back - I'm curious about it.

Comment: I also thought that maybe I should wait few hours so I tried to wait 24+ hours but with the same result. Right now I tried to create and setup this web app again on the first account (in order to verify whether this URL has already been taken by someone else as Thiago suggested). Surprisingly, with the first account I could successfully created this web site..

Comment: After deleting it from the first account again and attempting to create it on the second account again, I get the same error. So I am guessing that such movement of the hostname from one Azure account to another Azure account is simply not possible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this worked for me without any issues. created a webapp on one account, deleted it after and created on another account.

Comment: Then I have no clue why I am getting this error over and over. Have you deleted just App Service or also App Service Plan? Have you had both App Service Plans in the same region? Are your accounts completely separated and independent from each other?

Comment: yeah, accounts completely independent. deleted both app service and app service plan. not sure about the region, tbh

Comment: I do not know why or how, but it succeded this time (after maybe 15 attemtps alltogether). Unfortunately I cannot say why it was not working before, I followed the same steps each time (the only difference this time was that I let Application Insights active, but I strongly doubt that it has something to do with it).

Comment: It will not effect suddenly actually when on different accounts. I don't know the exact reason but it will take some time to create same name webapp in other account

Answer (score 1):

As you have already created CNAME for the website with your old subscription, that needs to be de-associate to use it again with your new subscription.

Comment: i would assume Azure deletes the DNS record when you delete the App Service but this is still a good answer. in cases where you have custom DNS